# Do synonyms apply to interesting/ignored tags?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

As per title, are synonyms applied to those too automatically?

And if not, should they?

EDIT: A bit clarification, I mean that if I have a tag with synonyms or a synonym for another tag marked as interesting/ignored, does it include the synonyms/"actual" tag too or is it just the specific tags I have listed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it does not.

I think the correct behavior would be to remap all the interesting tags when synonyms are introduced