# Remap Interesting Tags When Synonymed

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, tag-watching

I recently found that a tag I had as an Interesting Tag had been synonymed (foolishly), and now I wasn't getting any highlighting.  How about (as per [Waffles suggestion here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60656/do-synonyms-apply-to-interesting-ignored-tags/61126#61126)) we remap those Interesting Tags for a user once they've been synonymed?

Comment: I figured this did occur already.